# Use product tags for meta keywords in Opencart 1.5.3.1

Tags: opencart

I'd like to use my product tags as meta keywords on every product page. Can anyone help me with this code?

Thaks

Answer (score 0):

Below are some tips and they are general but give a direction of the different approaches to do this. Step 4 is a bit obvious. I am sorry but this not a module request forum, your question I think is fair so this direction set should get you in the right direction.

1 - Open `catalog/view/theme/default/product/product.tpl`

And do a find and replace with the header echo:

```
<?php

$getKeysandReplace=$header;
$getKeysandReplace=str_replace("<meta name=", "");

?>
```

Understand? Or use a regex to delete the Meta Keyword and Meta Description from the `$header` string and replace them with your own on the `product.tpl` - just grab the tags echo in the below code.

```
<?php if ($tags) { ?>
  <div class="tags"><b><?php echo $text_tags; ?></b>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($tags); $i++) { ?>
    <?php if ($i < (count($tags) - 1)) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $tags[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $tags[$i]['tag']; ?></a>,
    <?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $tags[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $tags[$i]['tag']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
```

2 - You can edit `header.tpl` and do a `IF($GET` or `if page is product type page` then display this `Meta Tag` or display the normal tags.

3 - You can do an SQL crob job that copies the product tags, and places them as product keywords in your database everyday.

4 - Make sure staff copy and paste the tags as keywords to in the admin panel - stating the obvious